# Can't launch outlook in visual studio through TFS add-in

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, outlook-addin

I am using visual studio 2013 with Team foundation Server add-in. Opening up a TFS task/bug item, there is a outlook icon button, which allow me to open up outlook new email with the TFS item title.

my visual studio runs in administrator mode.
I have two office versions installed (office 2013 and office 2016.)
Each time when I switch office versions, I will do a repair for the office version. and most time I was using office 2013 and everything works fine including open outlook through TFS add-on.

today, suddenly I couldn't open outlook through the TFS add-on, the error is

*Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)).*

I repaired office 2013, but didn't work.

some one knows other possibilities of the issue?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root issue is that the Version reference for the TypeLib created by the Outlook installation is pointing to a incorrect value.

> The root issue is that their is a problem with the Outlook
>   installation Common Object Model (COM) interface where the version
>   referencefor the TypeLib entry set by the Outlook installation is
>   pointing to a incorrect value/version or that version does not point
>   to a correct location. If you continue to have issues
>   then you may beed to reinstall Microsoft Outlook. **Repairing the
>   Outlook installation does not fix this issue so a reinstall is
>   suggested.**

Just following the steps mentioned in below article to fix that: https://www.fieldstonsoftware.com/support/support_gsyncit_8002801D.shtml

Just verify that with `Regedit.exe`, check below keys:

```
 HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\TypeLib

 HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
```

Verify if the type library  (GUID should be `{00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`) is indeed properly registered, using the correct type library version number.

[image]

Comment: You get it right. the issue on my machine is about step #2 => 2.even I uninstalled office 2016, there is a 9.6 version key there. it caused the problem. marked your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Andy's post is right. you can follow the instructions to find out the issue.

Office 2016 registry key is 9.6, on my machine, even I uninstalled office 2016, the registry key 9.6 still exists at

Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib{00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}

After deleting it, TFS office add-on works fine now. I think the add-on is trying to use the latest version and it causes the issue.